# maven project as dependency in gradle project

Tags: maven, gradle

I have a project which is using Gradle as build tool and a second subproject which is using Maven's POM. I don't have the freedom of changing build tool on the subproject.

What I want to achieve is to add my project with Maven POM as dependency on my Gradle project.

Where root (current dir) is my project with Gradle and contains the `build.gradle`, the Maven project is under `vendor/other-proj/` with POM file just under that directory.

I have tried these variations on my `build.gradle` file:

1st try:

```
include("vendor/other-proj/")
project(':other-proj') {
    projectDir = new File("vendor/other-proj/pom.xml")
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':other-proj')
}
```

2nd try:

```
dependencies {
    compile project('vendor/other-proj/')
}
```

3rd try:

```
dependencies {
    compile project('vendor/other-proj/pom.xml')
}
```

4th try:

```
dependencies {
    compile files 'vendor/other-proj/pom.xml'
}
```

I can't find anything related on the web, it seems most Gradle/Maven use cases are affected by publishing to Maven or generating POM, but I dont want to do any of those.

Can anybody point me to right direction?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can "fake" including a Maven project like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile files("vendor/other-proj/target/classes") {
        builtBy "compileMavenProject"
    }
}

task compileMavenProject(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "vendor/other-proj/"
    commandLine "/usr/bin/mvn", "clean", "compile"
}
```

This way Gradle will execute a Maven build (`compileMavenProject`) before compiling. But be aware that it is not a Gradle "project" in the traditional sense and will not show up, e.g. if you run `gradle dependencies`. It is just a hack to include the compiled class files in your Gradle project.

Edit:
You can use a similar technique to also include the maven dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile files("vendor/other-proj/target/classes") {
        builtBy "compileMavenProject"
    }
    compile files("vendor/other-proj/target/libs") {
        builtBy "downloadMavenDependencies"
    }
}

task compileMavenProject(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "vendor/other-proj/"
    commandLine "/usr/bin/mvn", "clean", "compile"
}

task downloadMavenDependencies(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "vendor/other-proj/"
    commandLine "/usr/bin/mvn", "dependency:copy-dependencies", "-DoutputDirectory=target/libs"
}
```

Comment: however this way the dependencies of that library is not loaded, is there any way to fix that?

Comment: It is shocked me that there is no a plugin

Comment: Is vice versa possible? I mean If I want to include a gradle project inside a maven one.

Comment: It does not appear that including the `libs` directory by using the `files` works. I keep getting `NoClassDefFoundError`s for the classes that are the dependencies of the Maven subproject.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot "include" a maven project in gradle settings.gradle. The simplest way would be to build the maven project and install it to your local repo using `mvn install`(can be default .m2, or any other custom location) and then consume it from your gradle project using groupname:modulename:version

```
repositories{
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies{
    implementation 'vendor:otherproj:version'
}
```

It is possible to depend directly on the jar of the maven project using `compile files` but this isn't ideal because it wont fetch transitive dependencies and you'll have to add those manually yourself.

Comment: That was not an option for me to install it on local repo due to a lot of problems mostly because it should have been recompiled each time after a change, independently of main project. Which obviously is a pain.

Comment: When I try this, I get: could not parse POM, already seen doctype.

Comment: `compile` can't be used from Gradle 7.0 (Apr 9, 2021).

Comment: @lamrongol you can, and it is acceptable, to edit the answer to modernize it.